# Remove row with PHPSpreadsheet-Library

Tags: php, phpspreadsheet

i want to remove a row in the excel-File with php. I'm using for it the PHPSpreadsheet-Library.

Now i've searched a lot but can't find any method how i can remove a row in the excel file.

Do anyone have an idea which function i can use for it?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like there's a `Worksheet::removeRow()` method for this.

https://scrutinizer-ci.com/g/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet/code-structure/master/operation/PhpOffice%5CPhpSpreadsheet%5CWorksheet%5CWorksheet%3A%3AremoveRow

So while I've never worked with PHPSpreadhseet, I guess it would be something like `$myWorkSheetObject->removeRow(13);` if you wanted to remove row 13 from a worksheet object called $myWorkSheetObject.